# I would like to create an multidimensional array of arrays of String from an array of String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of Strings, and I would like to group the content by three to create arrays within the array.

For instance:

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["a0", "a1", a2", "b0", "b1", "b2"]
```

And I am looking to achieve:

```
var multiDimensionalArray = [["a0", "a1", a2"], ["b0", "b1", "b2"]]
```

Therefore, I am looking for a function that could group the elements within arrayOfStrings in arrays containing 3 elements, in the right order.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
func makeMultidimensional(a: [String]) -> [[String]] {
    var result: [[String]] = []
    for var i = 0; i < a.count; i += 3 {
        result.append([a[i], a[i + 1], a[i + 2]])
    }
    return result
}

print(makeMultidimensional(arrayOfStrings)) // prints [["a0", "a1", "a2"], ["b0", "b1", "b2"]]
```

It iterates over array of strings and adds new array of 3 items to the result every time.

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
NSArray *multiDimensionalArray = @[@[@"a0", @"a1", @"a2"], @[@"b0", @"b1", @"b2"]];
```

for swift

```
var multiDimensionalArray = [["a0", "a1", "a2"], ["b0", "b1", "b2"]];
```

runnig on my system well

Comment: I think OP is looking for solutions in Swift

Comment: Well Bhai Jagveer OP want a solution. He knows how to declare `multiDimensionalArray ` (as you did) , look in his question.

Comment: great  thanks, actualy i dont understand the quetion!!

Answer (score 0):

```
func makeMultidimensional<T>(input:[T], dimensions:Int) -> [[T]]?
{
    if dimensions <= 0 || count(input) % dimensions > 0 {
        return nil
    }

    return
        input.reduce(([[T]](), [T]())) {
            if 0..<dimensions-1 ~= count($0.1) {
                return ($0.0, $0.1 + [$1])
            }
            else {
                return ($0.0 + [$0.1 + [$1]], [])
            }
        }.0
}
```